# How to trash all local git changes and revert to old commit?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

So here's the scenario, I've got a project that has a number of commits, and recently I installed a load of new packages to my project and initiated them.

I went and committed these changes (haven't pushed) but then realised I had forgot to test a core component.  Testing failed miserably, and I have now made such a mess of my code, my project fails to build and I cannot resolve it.

I can select a previous commit and check it out, which reverts any changed files, however any files added by the new packages still exist.

Is there anyway to clear the lot out, and have my working copy identical to one of my commits?

Comment: Have you heard of `reset --hard`? Sounds like it could be what you need. Be sure to read up about it before using it

Answer (score 8):

`git reset --hard <good commit>` will [reset](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) all *tracked* files from your working copy.

`git clean -df` will [clean](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) your working directory from files that are *not tracked*. `-d` will delete directories that are not tracked.

Use both of these with care.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the nudge from @Tim Castelijns

```
git reset --hard <commit number>
```

Resets your current branch to  and then makes the files in your working tree the same as the versions in

You'll still be left with all the untracked files, however a

```
git clean -f
```

will remove all untracked files, so your working copy and latest commit should now match  exactly